# Can I use Overlayfs on Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, kernel-modules, overlayfs

I'm running on Debian stable buster, and I'm trying to manually mount some directories using overlayfs.

I installed the package `fuse-overlayfs`. But when I run the command $ mount -t overlayfs ... I get the error

```
unknown filesystem type 'overlayfs'
```

Is it not possible to use overlayfs?

I can see that overlayfs is not listed in /proc/filesystems.

Note: I am running Linux kernel 5.10 installed from backports. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: There is probably some confusion between `mount -t overlay` (no `'fs` suffix) which uses the kernel version of overlayfs, and `fuse-overlayfs ...` which is the mount command used for the fuse version (which allows non-root users to mount).

Answer (score 1):

Meuh is correct. I should have been using

```
mount -t overlay
```

More information here https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Overlay_filesystem