# Error: kernel does not support overlay fs: 'overlay' is not supported over extfs

Tags: debian, fuse, overlayfs, podman

When I run podman with `--storage-opt ignore_chown_errors=true` I am getting

> Error: kernel does not support overlay fs: 'overlay' is not supported over extfs at `/home/user/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay`: backing file system is unsupported for this graph driver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because on Debian you do not have a kernel driver for overlayfs: so you'll need to use a userspace filesystem driver for overlayfs. First make sure it's installed,

```bash
sudo apt install fuse-overlayfs
```

Then add this argument to `podman` (**NOT `podman run`**),

```bash
--storage-opt mount_program=/usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs
```

In your case it should look like this

```bash
podman --storage-opt mount_program=/usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs --storage-opt ignore_chown_errors=true run [...]
```

---

This option can also be set in `~/.config/containers/storage.conf` under `mount_program`

Comment: The option `mount_program` can also be set in `storage.conf` under `[storage.options.overlay]`

Comment: Really? I see references to Debian having overlayfs only last year https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/658030/20140. Which version of debian does not have overlayfs?

Comment: Are you running this as "rootless" if so, the problem is most likely that non-root users cannot use the kernel mount driver and can only use the fuse mount.  This is referenced in a known bug: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8705#issuecomment-744116068